# What is exactly Linux From Scratch?

Tags: kernel, 15.04, compiling, development, source

I want to developing a Linux From Scratch but is that custom Linux like based on some kind of linux ? I installed an ubuntu, when I make LFS it would be base on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the FAQ](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/faq/#what-is-lfs):

> LFS stands for Linux From Scratch which is a project that aims to
>   teach you about the inner workings of Linux by building a Linux system
>   by downloading, building, and installing the packages yourself.

Since you download, build and install the whole thing yourself, it's not based on Ubuntu.

Comment: so LFS is an independence Linux Distribution ?

Comment: I wouldn't call it a distribution, but it is independent.

Comment: And how if i want to build a custom linux like Ubuntu or Linux Mint?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/49679/158442